# AMCharts gridColor

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Using AMCharts and have run into some issues. I can get the grid thickness and alpha  to work, but cant seem to make the gridColor to work. I have tried moving it into the valueAxes as suggested but did not work there either. I did try setting parseDates to true as well but it didn't budge.

**this is the code:**

options="{
            synchronizeGrid:false,
            rotate:theRotate,

```
        categoryAxis:{
        gridThickness:2,
        gridAlpha:.1,
        gridColor:'#ffff00',
        },

        chartCursor:{
        enabled:theCursor, 
        cursorColor:'red',
        cursorAlpha:1,
        categoryBalloonDateFormat:'MMM DD/YYYY, hh:mm:ss',
        },



        legend:{
        enabled:false, 
        textClickEnabled:true,
        align: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'',
        backgroundAlpha:0,
        fontSize:16,
        valueWidth:100,
        valueAlign: 'left',
        switchable:true,
        spacing:5,
        color:'',
        title:''},

        valueAxes:[
        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min1,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max1,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color1,
        color:point1Color,
        id: 'left',
        position: 'left',
        offset:0,
        axisThickness: 2,
        title:'',
        titleColor:'',
        gridAlpha:.05,
        gridThickness:2,
        },

        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min2,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max2,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color2,
        color:point2Color,
        id: 'right',
        position: 'right',
        offset: 0,
        axisThickness: 2,
        },

        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min3,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max3,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color3,
        color:point3Color,
        id: 'left-2',
        position: 'left',
        offset: 45,
        axisThickness: 2,
        },

        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min4,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max4,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color4,
        color:point4Color,
        id: 'right-2',
        position: 'right',
        offset: 45,
        axisThickness: 2,
        },

        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min5,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max5,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color5,
        color:point5Color,
        id: 'left-4',
        position: 'left',
        offset: 90,
        axisThickness: 2,
        },

        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min6,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max6,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color6,
        color:point6Color,
        id: 'right-4',
        position: 'right',
        offset: 90,
        axisThickness: 2,
        },

        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min7,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max7,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color7,
        color:point7Color,
        id: 'left-6',
        position: 'left',
        offset: 135,
        axisThickness: 2,
        },

        {strictMinMax: true,
        minimum:getItem.jsonData.Min8,
        maximum:getItem.jsonData.Max8,
        axisColor:getItem.jsonData.color8,
        color:point8Color,
        id: 'right-6',
        position: 'right',
        offset: 135,
        axisThickness: 2,
        }
        ]}"
```

Comment: Assuming you're using AmCharts v3, your code [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/pjn74ty3/) when used in both the categoryAxis and valueAxes. Please post your full makeChart code.

Comment: I have updated post with all the options code

Comment: Your option object is being passed as a string but you have what looks like variable names inside your string for the value axes, which definitely won't work. The category axis should work correctly since the values are literal strings.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. There are several parameters that have been populated with variables. They come from an array  that holds   the min,max,axis colors , pen colors etc. for several users. The idea is that each user can config their chart the way the want it and save it. So far it seems to work all the user configs seem to load up correctly when selected. I didnt know better. I will be certain to check that over. The only thing not working is the grid color. It was requested to be changeable because the user wanted a background color  that didnt work with the current  grid color.

Comment: thanks xorspark!  There was issues with the variables in the strings. Iam correcting this.